# TypeError: home.removeClass is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.refreshHome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a feature which when I click on my navbar, the animation restarts on the click, but I can't seem to make it work

JAVSCRIPT

```
const homeButton = document.getElementById('li-home');
const home = document.getElementById('home');

function refreshHome() {
    home.removeClass('logo-animation')
    home.addClass('logo-animation');
    setTimeout(function() {
        home.classList.remove('logo-animation');
    }, 1000);
}

homeButton.onclick = refreshHome;
```

CSS class

```
.home-animation {
    animation: tracking-in-contract 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000) both;
}
```

HTML

```
        <header id="home">
            <div class="logo logo-animation" data-glitch="Soccmai">
                <div class="glitch-bloc">
                    <p class="invisible-text">{ soccmai }</p>
                    <p class="glitchedAnim">{ soccmai }</p>
                    <p class="glitchedAnim">{ soccmai }</p>
                    <p class="glitchedAnim">{ soccmai }</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="underLogo">
                <h2>Web Developer | Graphic Designer</h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#home' id="li-home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#about-me'>About Me</a></li>
                <li>Projects</li>
                <li>Skills</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I tried adding addClass, removeClass, or classList.add, classList.remove, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: remove `this._` before home

Comment: What do you expect `this._home` to be?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston That wouldn't make any sense. You would (if that would work) remove `logo-animation` from `home` and then add it again in the next line.

Comment: I changed it to make sense, and now it gives me a different error "TypeError: home.removeClass is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.refreshHome"

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros i don't know thats what I found on google

Comment: _"I changed it to make sense"_ - So you first posted a invalid question? Why? _"and now it gives me a different error"_ - Changing the problem _after_ posting the question is a terrible idea because it can/will invalidate all comments/answers that have been posted for the previous version of the question.

Comment: I posted an invalid question because my code was invalid too

Comment: There are no `removeClass` and `addClass` methods on `Element`s.

Comment: Then you haven't done enough [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to a) fix the error on your own and b) create a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is `classList.add` not `.addClass`. I think you might be trying to use the JQuery library.

See classList for more info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: You haven't found a duplicate that shows how to add/remove a class with Vanilla JS?

Comment: @Andreas I want all the glory for myself?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use it like this

```js
const homeButton = document.getElementById('li-home');
const home = document.getElementById('home');

function refreshHome() {
    home.classList.remove('logo-animation')
    home.classList.add('logo-animation');
    setTimeout(function() {
        home.classList.remove('logo-animation');
    }, 1000);
}

homeButton.onclick = refreshHome;
```